# Outer Glow Effect and rotation On A Label in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create an outer glow effect on a label and make it rotate a little (by about 20 degrees). I'm using the following code, but it's not working the way I want it to:

```
<Label Height="106" Margin="80,57,36,0" Name="lblHeading" FontSize="35">
    Brian's 15th Birthday Party
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="100" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" 
                          Color="White"/>
    </Label.Effect>
</Label>
```

Is it possible to add some text somewhere in the Window and add an outer glow effect and rotation to it? It would be great if anyone can help me out with adding the same effect on a label or any other way to do so without using a label control.

I tried the following, too, but it's not helping. Maybe I don't know how to use it because it's just causing an error:

```
<OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Blue" GlowSize="30" Noise="1" Opacity="0.4" />
```

Comment: I am very much new to WPF so simple code or help with a little explaination is more appreciated.

Comment: Bitmap Effects were deprecated in .Net 4, So if you are using that version that will be why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You'll probably want to use a smaller `BlurRadius`, setting it to 100 will make the effect close to invisible. I suggest 10.
2. Set the [`RenderTransformOrigin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) to the point you want the text to rotate around (`0.5, 0.5` means rotate around the center).
3. Add a `RotateTransform` inside `Label.RenderTransform`.

The complete code should look close to this:

```
<Label Height="106" Margin="80,57,36,0" Name="lblHeading" FontSize="35"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    Brian's 15th Birthday Party
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" 
                      Color="White"/>
    </Label.Effect>
    <Label.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="20"/>
    </Label.RenderTransform>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can rotate your label:

```
<Label>
  <Label.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="20"/>
  </Label.LayoutTransform>
  <Label.Content>text</Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Comment: +1 to Codesparkle - beat me to it and more complete (its tough typing an an iPad!) - was goin to work on the glow part once i'd posted, but too late now!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through modification in `ControlTemplate`.

The key point is using two `ContentPresenter` to display your text, and attach `BlurEffect` to one `ContentPresenter`.

The code:

```
<Label Content="TestContent" Foreground="White" FontSize="20">
    <Label.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
            <Border>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                            <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
                        </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Label.Template>
</Label>
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhqh1.png)